# Algorithm to discriminate diagonals in a set of 6 segments defined by 4 points

Tags: geometry

here's a geometric problem that I've been unsuccessful to solve:

- we have four points ***A, B, C, D*** defining an area
- We know the ***(x, y)*** coordinates of each point.

There are **6** segments connecting **2** points:

- **AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD**

One of the intersections of these segments will form a point ***inside*** the figure: the intersection of the two diagonals.

There are **3** possible for couples of diagonals:

- ***[AB]*** and ***[CD]***
- ***[AC]*** and ***[BD]***
- ***[AD]*** and ***[BC]***

(see the figure below)

[image]

I am searching for a simple algorithm to find which of the 3 possible cases is happening when I vary the ***(x, y)*** coordinates of ***A, B, C, D***

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the midpoint of each segment and check to see if it is in the interior.

Comment: Suppose ABCD is not convex. Or even self-intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find two distinct points among $\{A,B,C,D\}$,
you may arbitrarily consider any of your proposed choices for the diagonals, as you prefer.
Otherwise, let us assume without loss of generality that $A,B$ are distinct.

The points $(x,y)$ on the line $AB$ fulfill $d_{AB}(x,y)=0$ where
$$d_{AB}(x,y) = (y_B-y_A) (x - x_A) + (x_A-x_B) (y - y_A)$$
and points $(x,y)$ not on the line $AB$ will yield either positive $d_{AB}(x,y)$ or negative $d_{AB}(x,y)$, depending on which side of the line they are located.

Now, if $d_{AB}(x_C,y_C)$ has the same nonzero sign as $d_{AB}(x_D,y_D)$, then the closed segment $AB$ has interior points of the polygon $ABCD$ only on one of its sides, and it does not contain further vertices, therefore it is not a diagonal.

If $d_{AB}(x_C,y_C)$ and $d_{AB}(x_D,y_D)$ have opposite nonzero signs, then the segment $AB$ has interior points of the polygon on both of its sides and is therefore a diagonal.

If, say, $d_{AB}(x_C,y_C)=0$ but $d_{AB}(x_D,y_D)\neq0$, then the closed segment $AB$ may be considered a diagonal if and only if it contains $C$, that is, if the sign of $d_{CD}(x_A,y_A)$ is different from the sign of $d_{CD}(x_B,y_B)$. (One of these signs may be zero.)

If $d_{AB}(x_C,y_C)=0=d_{AB}(x_D,y_D)$, then $A,B,C,D$ are collinear, and you may again consider any of your proposed choices for the diagonals, as you prefer.

Edit: When I wrote *polygon*, I meant its convex hull.